# Can GHCi tell me the type of a local Haskell function?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, ghci

Is it possible to query the ghci for the type it inferred for a function inside another function?

Answer (score 24):

This is a quick and ugly hack, but what I usually do is just use the function in the wrong way and read the error message:

```
inc x = x + 1
  where
    f (y, z) = y + z
    g = f :: Char
```

GHCi output:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Char'
       against inferred type `(t, t) -> t'
In the expression: f :: Char
```

Although this leaves out the context `Num t =>`, this usually does provide me with enough information to continue.

Comment: +1 Excellent! This really helped me to understand a hairy function definition! Note: this works on ***any*** expression in the function definition. For example if you want to see the type of `blah` in `f x = foo + blah`, do - `f x = foo + (let exp = blah in exp::Char)`.

Answer (score 12):

You might try doing it by setting a breakpoint on it, so the function is in scope from the debugger.

Also I think that EclipseFP can tell you the types of things when you mouse over them, at least some of the time.

Comment: Whoa, just realised that breakpoints where an option, after posting a convoluted half-baked solution... Then noticed this answer. GHCi prints out the types of expressions in current scope when it stops at a breakpoint without any special prodding, so it's just a matter of placement. +1!

Comment: Nice tip, but doesn't work if code doesn't compile. Tom's answer can come in handy.

Answer (score 7):

With GHC 7.8+, just append `` `asTypeOf` _ `` to the expression.

See [Find out the type of an expression/function with typed holes](http://ro-che.info/articles/2014-03-13-type-of-local-function.html) for a detailed explanation.